# How to prevent two labels to overlap in a barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The image below shows a chart that I created with the code below. I highlighted the missing or overlapping labels. Is there a way to tell ggplot2 to not overlap labels?

[image]

```
week = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)
statuses = c('Shipped', 'Shipped', 'Shipped', 'Shipped', 'Not-Shipped', 'Shipped', 'Shipped', 'Shipped', 'Not-Shipped', 'Shipped')

dat <- data.frame(Week = week, Status = statuses)

p <- qplot(factor(Week), data = dat, geom = "bar", fill = factor(Status))
p <- p + geom_bar()
# Below is the most important line, that's the one which displays the value
p <- p + stat_bin(aes(label = ..count..), geom = "text", vjust = -1, size = 3)
p
```

Comment: you can plot text at specific coordinates.  It's not the best approach, but it will get the job done.

Comment: @Ricardo: That's an idea, but the bar could be of any height.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a variant of the well-known [population pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_pyramid).

Some sample data (code inspired by Didzis Elferts' answer):

```
set.seed(654)
week <- sample(0:9, 3000, rep=TRUE, prob = rchisq(10, df = 3))
status <- factor(rbinom(3000, 1, 0.15), labels = c("Shipped", "Not-Shipped"))
data.df <- data.frame(Week = week, Status = status)
```

Compute count scores for each week, then convert one category to negative values:

```
library("plyr")
plot.df <- ddply(data.df, .(Week, Status), nrow)
plot.df$V1 <- ifelse(plot.df$Status == "Shipped",
                     plot.df$V1, -plot.df$V1)
```

Draw the plot. Note that the y-axis labels are adapted to show positive values on either side of the baseline.

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(plot.df) + 
  aes(x = as.factor(Week), y = V1, fill = Status) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 100 *     -1:5, 
                     labels = 100 * c(1, 0:5)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = sign(V1) * max(V1) / 30, label = abs(V1)))
```

The plot:

[image: plot]

For production purposes you'd need to determine the appropriate y-axis tick labels dynamically.

Answer (score 7):

Made new sample data (inspired by code of @agstudy).

```
week <- sample(0:5,1000,rep=TRUE,prob=c(0.2,0.05,0.15,0.5,0.03,0.1))
statuses <- gl(2,1000,labels=c('Not-Shipped', 'Shipped'))
dat <- data.frame(Week = week, Status = statuses)
```

Using function `ddply()` from library `plyr` made new data frame `text.df` for labels. Column `count` contains number of observations in each combination of `Week` and `Status`. Then added column `ypos` that contains cumulative sum of `count` for each Week plus 15. This will be used for y position. For `Not-Shipped` `ypos` replaced with -10.

```
library(plyr)
text.df<-ddply(dat,.(Week,Status),function(x) data.frame(count=nrow(x)))
text.df<-ddply(text.df,.(Week),transform,ypos=cumsum(count)+15)
text.df$ypos[text.df$Status=="Not-Shipped"]<- -10
```

Now labels are plotted with `geom_text()` using new data frame.

```
ggplot(dat,aes(as.factor(Week),fill=Status))+geom_bar()+
  geom_text(data=text.df,aes(x=as.factor(Week),y=ypos,label=count))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One solution to avoid overlaps is to use to dodge position of bars and texts. To avoid missing values you can set `ylim`. Here an example.

[image]

```
##  I create some more realistic data similar to your picture
week <- sample(0:5,1000,rep=TRUE)
statuses <- gl(2,1000,labels=c('Not-Shipped', 'Shipped'))
dat <- data.frame(Week = week, Status = statuses)

## for dodging
dodgewidth <- position_dodge(width=0.9)
## get max y to set ylim
ymax <- max(table(dat$Week,dat$Status))+20
ggplot(dat,aes(x = factor(Week),fill = factor(Status))) + 
  geom_bar( position = dodgewidth ) +
  stat_bin(geom="text", position= dodgewidth, aes( label=..count..),
           vjust=-1,size=5)+
  ylim(0,ymax)
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Didzis plot you could also increase readability by keeping the position on the y axis constant and by colouring the text in the same colour as the legend.

```
library(ggplot2)
week <- sample(0:5,1000,rep=TRUE,prob=c(0.2,0.05,0.15,0.5,0.03,0.1))
statuses <- gl(2,1000,labels=c('Not-Shipped', 'Shipped'))
dat <- data.frame(Week = week, Status = statuses)


library(plyr)
text.df<-ddply(dat,.(Week,Status),function(x) data.frame(count=nrow(x)))
text.df$ypos[text.df$Status=="Not-Shipped"]<- -15
text.df$ypos[text.df$Status=="Shipped"]<- -55

p <- ggplot(dat,aes(as.factor(Week),fill=Status))+geom_bar()+
geom_text(data=text.df,aes(x=as.factor(Week),y=ypos,label=count),colour=ifelse(text.df$Status=="Not-Shipped","#F8766D","#00BFC4"))
```

[image]