# Cross table graph similar to excel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to put a 3D kind of graph similar to attached image created in excel. I am not sure whether we can do this in ggplot?

[image: cross table image]

```
structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), P = c(15089, NA, 
NA, 43083), Q = c(1589, NA, NA, 18120), R = c(93751, NA, 4709, 
211649), S = c(34167, 1323, 1520, 82378), T = c(8831, NA, 4544, 
15157)), .Names = c("Name", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have worked with this following code.

```
ggplot(a, aes(x = a$A, y = a$Amount, fill = a$B)) + 
geom_col(position = 'stack') + 
geom_text(aes(label = a$Amount), position = position_stack(vjust = .5),
      color='grey25', size=2) + coord_flip()
```

The problem is the labels which shows on top the the graph is overlapping

Updated:
Actually, I thought I need to reshape the data to achieve this kind of graph, not so sure though. So I reshaped the like below

```
structure(list(AA = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), 
    BB = c("P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", 
    "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"), Amount = c(15089, 
    1589, 93751, 34167, 8831, NA, NA, NA, 1323, NA, NA, NA, 4709, 
    1520, 4544, 43083, 18120, 211649, 82378, 15157)), .Names = c("AA", 
"BB", "Amount"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried the following code to achieve this to which the labels are overlapping

```
ggplot(a, aes(x = AA, y = Amount, fill = BB)) + 
    geom_col(position = 'stack')+
    geom_text(aes(label = Amount), 
             position = position_stack(vjust = 0.2), 
              color='grey25', 
              size=2) +
    coord_flip()
```

Also, when I supply this to ggploty for shiny, the graph is not coming in dashboard

Comment: what have you tried so far? have you checked http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html  ?

Comment: You could also check [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization)

Comment: I have worked with this following code. The problem is the labels which shows on top the the graph is overlapping.ggplot(a, aes(x = a$A, y = a$Amount, fill = a$B)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'stack')+
  geom_text(aes(label = a$Amount), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5), 
            color='grey25', 
            size=2) +
  coord_flip()

Comment: @Lak023 your code in the comment does not match the variable names in the question. can you adapt it accordingly?

Comment: @Jan I updated the question

Comment: You have the graph working, but (now) your question is not about the graph, but rather how to have labels not overlap.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, yes the labels of BB are very near which leads to overlap of the values. This makes difficult to read the values and graph as clumpsy

Comment: @Lak023 check http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/01/avoid-overlapping-labels-in-ggplot2-charts.html for ggrepel which might help you or take a look at this solution (note quite what you want but maybe a solution anyway): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127170/how-to-prevent-two-labels-to-overlap-in-a-barchart